# Is there any way to disable Bootstrap for date picker?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a date picker made of JavaScript. I don't want it to be affected by [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). Is there any way to do it? Or I should use a Bootstrap date picker?

Comment: How is it affected by Bootstrap? You could place the styles for the datepicker inside a prefix like `.date-picker div` etc.

Comment: please create a jsFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thin you'll need to work around it manually. There are two things:

1. CSS: if Bootstrap overrides any CSS rules, you need to specify a more specific rule that will take precedence over what Bootstrap does. See here: http://juicystudio.com/article/selector-specificity.php
2. JS: if any JS affects the control, you'll most probably have to unregister all Bootstrap handlers (use Chrome debugger to see if there are any) and register the ones from datepicker manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify own css class for your datepicker and override bootstrap's styles